# Mysql query count total from other table

Tags: mysql

Table jenis_usaha

```
ID JENIS_USAHA  
1 Laundry  
2 Restauran
```

Table waralaba

```
ID ID_JENIS_USAHA  
1 1  
2 2
```

Table perusahaan

```
ID NAME ID_WARALABA  
1 A 1  
2 B 2  
3 C 1
4 D 1
```

Table outlet

```
ID ID_PERUSAHAAN  
1 1  
2 1  
3 2  
4 2  
5 1  
6 1  
7 1  
8 1  
9 1
```

The result that I want is like this

```
ID JENIS_USAHA TOTAL_PERUSAHAAN TOTAL_OUTLET  
1  Laundry          3                7   
2  Restauran        1                2
```

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT  ju.ID, 
        ju.JENIS_USAHA,
        COUNT(p.ID) AS TOTAL_PEMBERI,
                (SELECT count(o.ID)
                    FROM outlet o 
                    WHERE p.ID = o.ID_PERUSAHAAN
                        AND w.ID = p.ID_WARALABA
                        AND ju.ID = w.ID_JENIS_USAHA
                    ) AS TOTAL_OUTLET
FROM jenis_usaha ju
            LEFT JOIN waralaba w ON w.ID_JENIS_USAHA = ju.ID
            LEFT JOIN perusahaan p ON p.ID_WARALABA = w.ID           
GROUP BY ju.ID
```

I've got no error BUT a wrong result for TOTAL_OUTLET. Could you please show me the right query for this? thanks

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help if you included some sample data, expected results and actual results. Simply telling us it is wrong doesn't give us much to go on! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: yes i have add more info with sample data. thank you

Comment: Your query contains `ID_PENERIMA_WARALABA` but the `outlet` table doesn't include this field.

Comment: sorry my mistake. just fixed it. thanks

Comment: If I run your query, I get the results you are expecting.

Comment: i have  add the data for outlet table. please check if it the right query for the result. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did the wrong join that's why you got wrong output
below query should work as your way

```
  select j.id ,j.name,TOTAL_PERUSAHAAN,outlet as TOTAL_OUTLET 
  from  jenis_usaha j inner join         
    (select p.id,count(o.ID_PERUSAHAAN) as outlet from outlet o
    inner join perusahaan p
    on o.ID_PERUSAHAAN=p.id
    group by p.id
    ) t1 
    on t1.id=j.id
    inner join 
    (        
    select w.id, count(p.ID_WARALABA) as TOTAL_PERUSAHAAN  
    from  waralaba w inner join perusahaan p
    on w.id=p.ID_WARALABA
    group by w.id
      ) t2
      on t2.id=j.id


id  name    TOTAL_PERUSAHAAN    TOTAL_OUTLET
1   Laundry     3                   7
2   Restauran   1                   2
```

here is fiddle link where you can find details

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/400c971/6

Comment: @Faiz can you check this query ?

Comment: that is awesome. The query is correct for the case. But when I tried to the real DB it show empty data for the result. Please take a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7afc17/2 it has the same structure with the example. Thank you Zaynul

Comment: ok after looking i will inform you right a bit busy but i think issue can be join related (based on id)

Comment: your sample table structure that you given and the structure of the link is not same thats why you get 0 row as a outcome

Comment: really?? I really sorry, it is hard for me to write the db in here and I've just found about sqlfiddle as well. Please help me with the query. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177481/discussion-between-faiz-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Comment: Hi Zaynul, could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51806487/6144233 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was taking very long to understand your query, so I decided to do my own.
This one bring the results you wanted anyway. Please check if this works for your case. =)

Btw, `st` stands for subtotal

```
SELECT 
    st.id,
    st.name,
    count(ps_id) AS ps_amount,
    sum(ol_amount) AS ol_amount
FROM 
    (SELECT
        ju.id,
        ju.name,
        ps.id AS ps_id,
        count(ol.id) as ol_amount
    FROM
        jenis_usaha ju
    INNER JOIN
        waralaba wl 
        ON wl.id_jenis_usaha = ju.id
    LEFT JOIN
        perusahaan ps
        ON ps.id_waralaba = wl.id
    LEFT JOIN
        outlet AS ol
        ON ol.id_perusahaan = ps.id
        GROUP BY 
            ju.id,
            ju.name,
            ps.id) st
GROUP BY
    st.id,
    st.name
```