# mysql combine two query into one query

Tags: mysql

I want two combine this two query into one query

```
SELECT p.NAMA_PT AS PT_PEMBERI
FROM perusahaan p
LEFT JOIN penerima_waralaba pw ON pw.ID_PERUSAHAAN = p.ID
LEFT JOIN outlet o ON o.ID_PENERIMA_WARALABA = pw.ID
LEFT JOIN nomor_logo nl ON nl.ID = o.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA
WHERE nl.NOMOR_LOGO = 'WI-0010205-610'
```

and this

```
SELECT pw.NAMA_PT AS PT_PENERIMA
FROM penerima_waralaba pw
LEFT JOIN outlet o ON o.ID_PENERIMA_WARALABA = pw.ID
LEFT JOIN nomor_logo nl ON nl.ID = o.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA
WHERE nl.NOMOR_LOGO = 'WI-0010205-610'
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use join if two queries are fine then below will work

```
select t1.PT_PEMBERI,t2.PT_PENERIMA from
(SELECT nl.ID, p.NAMA_PT AS PT_PEMBERI
    FROM perusahaan p
    LEFT JOIN penerima_waralaba pw ON pw.ID_PERUSAHAAN = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN outlet o ON o.ID_PENERIMA_WARALABA = pw.ID
    LEFT JOIN nomor_logo nl ON nl.ID = o.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA
    WHERE nl.NOMOR_LOGO = 'WI-0010205-610'
    )t1
  inner join
  (
    SELECT nl.ID,pw.NAMA_PT AS PT_PENERIMA
    FROM penerima_waralaba pw
    LEFT JOIN outlet o ON o.ID_PENERIMA_WARALABA = pw.ID
    LEFT JOIN nomor_logo nl ON nl.ID = o.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA
    WHERE nl.NOMOR_LOGO = 'WI-0010205-610
    )t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Comment: @Faiz does it works?

Comment: yes, but what I want is the result show PT_PEMBERI and PT_PENERIMA, because it different data. Not like this http://prntscr.com/khm5mr

Comment: @Faiz in two columns?

Comment: yes correct sir

Comment: @Faiz data type of two columns please number or varchar?

Comment: data type is text sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177893/discussion-between-faiz-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Answer (score 0):

You can used derived tables in your statement. Eg

Select X, Y from (select....) as table1 join (select....) As table2 etc.

See reference

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html